# Powershell test git branch with IndexOf doesn't work

Tags: powershell

This code doesn't work where "mybranch" is actually listed in git branch. If I write the same list manually in @ here string it works not if I set $string with git branch why ?

```
 $branch = "mybranch"
$string = git branch
$test = $string.IndexOf($branch)
```

$test always -1

Comment: Output from `git branch` is usually prefixed by whitespace + selected branch indicator. `$string = git branch |% TrimStart ' *'` should take care of it

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is probably to use [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) with the `-Quiet` switch:

```sh
# Searches *line by line*, looks for substring 'mybranch' on each, and
# exits once a match is found.
# Assigns $true, if found, $null otherwise (treated as $false in Boolean contexts).
# Note that Select-String accepts regexes by default, so you could match
# more strictly with '\bmybranch\b`, for instance.
$test = git branch | Select-String mybranch -Quiet
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

A fix to your approach requires joining the (typically) *multiple lines* that `git branch` outputs, one by one, to form a *single, multi-line string*:

```sh
$test = (git branch | Out-String).IndexOf('mybranch')
```

<sup>Note: [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) unfortunately appends a *trailing newline* to the resulting string, as discussed in [GitHub issue #14444](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14444). To avoid that, you could use `` ((git branch) -join "`n") `` instead.</sup>

Only then does `.IndexOf()` actually refer to the *string* type's method of that name, and performs the desired *literal substring search*.

Without that, and **with *two or more* `git branch` output lines, an *array* of strings (lines) is captured, and the *array* type's `.IndexOf()` method is called**, which tests *each element* for equality *in full*.

Given that `git branch` puts whitespace before the branch name on each output line, plus an `*` to indicate the current branch, lookup by the branch name alone therefore won't match (because it doesn't match a line *in full*), which is what happened in your case.

Note that this is **how PowerShell handles output from *all* external programs**:

- Output lines are *streamed*, one by one, as they become available.
- If you *capture* the output or use it as part of an *expression* (`(...)`):

  - If there's only *one* output line, that line is captured as-is, i.e. as a `[string]` instance.
  - If there are *two or more* output lines, they are captured in a regular PowerShell *array*, i.e. as an `[object[]]` instance whose elements are `[string]` instances, in this case.
  - If you want to ensure that a given call *always* results in an *array* - even if only *one* output line happens to be emitted - use `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--)